# How to find the derivative of a matrix if Y=AXBX^TC

Tags: matrices, derivatives

How to find the matrix derivative dY/dX, where Y=AXBX^TC and X: p x q, if the dimensions of X are unspecified. Determine the dimensions of the other matrices depending on the expression A, B, and C are constant matrices. Add dimension to the identity matrix.

Comment: Hi. For better readability please [edit] the question and use [math formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I think the expression in question is $$Y=A\,\left(X\,B\,X^{\intercal}\right)C$$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the product rule to the expression $$Y=A\,\left(X\,B\,X^{\intercal}\right)C$$ yields the following result

$$\begin{aligned}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}Y & =\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}\left(A\,\left(X\,B\,X^{\intercal}\right)C\right)\\
 & =A\,\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}\left(X\,B\,X^{\intercal}\right)C\\
 & =A\,\left(\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}X\right)\,B\,X^{\intercal}+X\,B\,\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}\left(X^{\intercal}\right)\right)C\\
 & =A\,\left(\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}X\right)\,B\,X^{\intercal}+X\,B\,\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm dX}}X\right)^{\intercal}\right)C\\
 & =A\,\left(I\,B\,X^{\intercal}+X\,B\,I^{\intercal}\right)C\\
 & =A\,\left(B\,X^{\intercal}+X\,B\right)C
\end{aligned}$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}  \def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\E{{\cal E}} \def\F{{\cal F}} \def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Eij{E_{ij}}
\def\Eji{E_{ji}}
\def\Xij{X_{ij}}
$First, recall that the component-wise self-gradients of $X$ are
$$\eqalign{
\grad X\Xij &= \Eij \qquad\qquad
\grad {X^T}\Xij &= \Eij^T = \Eji \\
}$$
where $\Eij$ is the so-called *Single Entry* matrix whose components are all equal to $0$ except for the $(i,j)$ component which equals $\o$.

This can be used to compute the component-wise gradient of $Y$
$$\eqalign{
Y &= AXBX^TC \\
\grad Y{\Xij}
 &= A\gradLR{X}{\Xij}BX^TC + AXB\gradLR{X^T}{\Xij}C \\
 &= A\Eij BX^TC + AXB\Eji C \\
}$$
The full **matrix-by-matrix** gradient is a fourth-order tensor
which cannot be written using standard matrix notation.